# Can I use ANAME (alias) to point domain to CloudFlare CDN?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

I'm searching for a CDN which renders an IP that I can set to the ANAME value on my DNS.

I tried using AWS CloudFront, but it does not render an IP for external DNS to point to.

**Does CloudFlare render an IP that can be used as the ANAME value on a DNS?**

I am not looking for a CNAME solution.

Comment: ANAME is a proprietary DNS extension, internal to a given provider, not a standard, and hence will not exist everywhere.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek there's an (expired) [draft RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-dnsop-aname-04) for standardizing ANAME

Comment: Yes, but HTTPS/SVCB records are bound to be soon a RFC and they completely superseed that and offer other new features, like TLS 1.3 ECH

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, you can not.  You must use CloudFlare's DNS.

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201720164-Creating-a-Cloudflare-account-and-adding-a-website

> Enter your website’s root domain and then click Add Site. For example, if your website is www.example.com, type example.com.
>
> Cloudflare attempts to automatically identify your DNS records. This process takes approximately 60 seconds to complete.

From there, you must update your nameserver to point to CloudFlare's DNS.

There is no way to simply ALIAS towards an IP of a CDN which serves your content.